# I can't create an apk using proguard on xamarin.android

Tags: android, xamarin.android, apk, proguard

I am trying to enable proguard in order to generate soft apks...but, when I set **Enable Proguard** as true and try to build the project, I see:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       "java.exe" exited with code 1.

[image]

Some sites say that people need a proguard configuration file, something like that....
I noticed there are proguard files here, but in my **obj** folder that is excluded from project...I don't know if it is really a problem:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do one or more of following:

1. Updating Proguard to latest version (*[Proguard on sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/proguard/files/)*)
2. Updating JDK to latest version
3. Set 1G as Java max heap size

   - *Right-click on project -> Properties -> Android Options -> Advanced*
4. Add `proguard.cfg` to the root of the project, right-click on it and set `Build Action` to `ProguardConfiguration` with following content:

   ```
   -dontwarn okio.**
   ```
5. Subscribe to [Error: "java.exe" exited with code 1 in Release mode](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/1369)

Note:

You need to match content of `proguard.cfg` based on used libraries, the above example is for [OkIO](https://github.com/square/okio)

Comment: where do I find proguard.conf? Do I need create that?

Comment: Yes, I mentioned that in my answer

Comment: I create a file as you said....I updated the jds, and the proguard folder and setted 1G....now the error is "Unknown option '´╗┐-dontwarn' in line 1 of file 'proguard.conf'"...it's related with UTF-8, right? How Do I save it as utf-8, please?

Comment: I save it using notepad ++ (UTF-8 without BOM) it seems it works...but many warning I can see know and the error "Please correct the above warnings first. PROGUARD"

Comment: I added only **-ignorewarnings** to the .config and now it builds and generates the apk...but the apk size is the same as before I enabled proguard...

Comment: but your answer solved the first error...then, I marked it...thanks

Comment: Sorry, I was offline, I did above steps for my project and still I could not get success build, so I opened that mentioned issue on Github. enabling proguard won't reduce apk size, it will be obfuscate the java codes.